# Spring MVC, Services, @transactional and return to Control stored entity

Tags: spring-mvc, service, persistence, transactional

I have a controller that save a entity using a service. This service have 2 parameters of 2 entities. The Service manage first entity, and save it. Later, call a second service for the second entity. This second service manages the second entity and save it.

My problem is that when the second service return to first service, the id of saved second entity is lost. (i dont understand why, but i need this stored entity).

No happend same when return service 1 to controller.

**controller**:

```
entity1Service.mergeAndSave(entity1, entity2)
```

**entity1Service**:

```
@Transactional
public void mergeAndSave(Entity1 entity1POST, Entity2 entity2POST) {
   Entity1 entity1ToSave = entity1DAO.findById(entity1POST.getId())
   ...
   more logic
   ...
   entity1DAO.save(entity1ToSave);
   entity2Service.saveEntity2ForEntity1(entity2POST, entity1ToSave)
   entity1POST = entity1ToSave
}
```

**entity2Service**:

```
@Transactional
public void saveEntity2ForEntity1(Entity2 entity2POST, Entity1 entity1ToSave) {
   Entity2 entity2ToSave = null;
   ...
   more logic
   ...
   entity2DAO.save(entity2ToSave);
   entity2POST = entity2ToSave;
}
```

entity2ToSave have id and more initialized fields later save, but when return to entity1Service lose data (entity2POST = before call to entity2Service.saveEntity2ForEntity1), but when entit1Service return to controller, entity1POST == entity1ToSave, not equal entity1POST before call mergeAndSave and save.

Any idea? I need both saved entities where return to controller.

Comment: Please add the code where you're comparing the objects.

Comment: hi, i dont compare objects... I try to show id in JSP to both entities, entity1.id != null, but entity2.id = null..... Im debuggin and look that info of entity2 disapair when the serivice2 method saveEntity2ForEntity1 return to caller method entity1service.

Comment: It should work. Did you see the value of entity2ToSave.id just after entity2DAO.save(entity2ToSave); ? or is there any others statements after entity2DAO.save(entity2ToSave); ?

Comment: yes, just after save, the id exists, later execute entity2POST = entity2ToSave and id exists in both intances..but when return to entity1Service... disapair. :S... i think taht is something with @transactional... but i dont understand what.